# Map model constructor with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is there a way in EF7 to force DbContext to create instance of my model by passing values to constructor not assigning them directly to the properties?

Docs tells me that I can interact with EF by providing it services. I found that IModelCustomizer is responsible for controlling how a model is created. But I'm not sure that if that is what I'm looking for nor how to implement that.